# Kotlin firebase read child of child data does not work

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to read firebase data on kotlin side. I can read one single child's `data(.child("user"))`, but if I tried to read under "id" `data(.child("user").child("id"))`, it will crash.

I tried every method but still, I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me out?

in addition, when I read data from iOS side, it worked with just adding .child(path) func but on Kotlin side, it does not work

```
private lateinit var database : DatabaseReference
private lateinit var sectionRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var sectionArrayList : ArrayList<SermonSection>


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_section)

    sectionRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sectionList)
    sectionRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    sectionRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    sectionArrayList = arrayListOf<SermonSection>()
    getData()

}

private fun getData() {

    //Database Declaration
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").child("id")
    database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            println("ERROR is --------> " + error)
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (userSnapShot in snapshot.children) {
                    val user = userSnapShot.getValue(SermonSection::class.java)
                    sectionArrayList.add(user!!)
                }
                sectionRecyclerView.adapter = SectionAdapter(sectionArrayList)
            }
        }

    })

}
```

for the SermonSection class has just two values of string
EX).
detailSection
sectionTitle

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. If the app crashes, there will be an error message and stack trace written to its logcat output. Please find this, and edit your question to include them - and the minimal code that produces that error.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen error says that
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ttolc_android, PID: 2011
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.ttolc_android.SermonSection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **detailSection** & **sectionTitle** and save it to **SermonSection** object, then you need to read the child under **id** called **password**

this:

```java
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").child("id").child("password")
```

Comment: password is a key value so no need to call it with func child(). It made a same crash too.